# Can't get Django forms to save to User and Profile model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to extend the Django User model by creating a user Profile model. When users register for the site, I want them to be able to select what class period they are in. To do this, I've tried to create a form that alters the User model, and a form that alters the Profile model. The problem is that when I try to put both forms into 'users/register.html' I am getting an error that says 'Anonymous User has to data _meta'. Below is my original code that only has the form for altering the User model in 'users/register.html'. How can I configure the registration so that users are able to save to the User and Profile model when they are first signing up for the site?

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    '''
    periods = [
        ('-','-'),
        ('1','1'),
        ('2','2'),
        ('3','3'),
        ('4','4'),
        ('6','6'),
        ('7','7'),
    ]
    '''
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    period = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Home')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Simpson')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    periods = [
        (1,1),
        (2,2),
        (3,3),
        (4,4),
        (6,6),
        (7,7),
    ]
    period = forms.ChoiceField(choices=periods)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','period']
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def save_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    context = {
        'title':'Login',
    }
    return render(request,'users/login.html',context)

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email_domain = re.search("@[\w.]+", email)
            if email_domain.group() == EMAIL_DOMAIN:
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request,f'Account created for {username}! You are now able to sign in.')
                return redirect('users-login')
            else:
                messages.error(request,f'Sorry. You are not authorized to register.')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    context = {
        'title':'Register',
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request,'users/register.html',context)
```

Comment: It means you are not logged in, try adding `login_required`.

Comment: Even if I want the user to enter all this information when registering for the first time?

Comment: Have you changed any manager? or its may be because of deleting any migration file by mistake.

Comment: Hello @Snerd error clearly explain you're trying to perform action on  [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser) which do not have some properties, provide full traceback.

Comment: Hey @AnkitTiwari I've updated the post to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are putting both the forms in the register page . When you have not created any user so how you can create a profile and how would you be able to add or retrieve data from it?

Now the solution for that is ,

1 . You create a page for registering the user say "users/register.html" , when they successfully register there, create a signal for creating the Profile for him , then successfully log the user in . Then redirect the just registered user to the profile change page.

2. Take both the forms in the user register page but do not validate the profile_change form .Create the user in the view and then reference it to the profile_change_form .

A simple code bit for that .

```
def registerUser(request) : 
    if request.method == "POST" :
        user_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get("username")
            # fields you require
            user = User(username = username , password = password)
            user.save()
            profile_field_objects = request.POST.get("profile_field_data")
            profile = Profile(user = user , profile_field_objects = profile_field_objects)
            profile.save()
     # rest you can code
```